# How to align text left in psTextFrame

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pstricks

How can I align text left in a psTextFrame?

Here's the example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,dvips]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-eps}


\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,runit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,2)
    \psset{linewidth=1pt}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, linewidth=1pt](0,0)(5,2)
    \psTextFrame(0.5,0.5)(4.5,1.5){\large\textbf{Left}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{TeXtoEPS}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `ref` parameter:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,2)
    \psset{linewidth=1pt}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, linewidth=1pt](0,0)(5,2)
    \psTextFrame[ref=lb](0.5,0.5)(4.5,1.5){\large\textbf{Left}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: set it left but doesn't look great - so I tried framesept but doesn't change anything. Is \space the only solution, moving text to the right?

Comment: `ref=lc`, `ref=rt` and so on. What exactly do you want?

Comment: When text is positioned left in the psTextFrame there is absolutely no spacing between the left margin of the frame and the text.

Comment: and where is the problem to write `~foo`?